# Вместо JSF + Spring + JPA на JSP + Spring MVC + JPA

Tags: maven, spring, java, jsp

Есть небольшой проект в виде таблиц для работы с данными (с сортировками, редактированием, добавлением) на JSF + Spring core + JPA. Меня попросили переписать на JSP. Раньше на JSP не писал, поэтому начал гуглить туториалы разные, разбираться с сервлетами и т.д.

В идеале не хотелось бы переписывать весь бек-энд, а только подшаманить все страницы с формами на JSP. При попытке прикрутить JSP-страницу к моему проекту спринг ее воспринимает, как что-то инородное, проект не стартует. Забыл упомянуть, что сборка Maven.

Собственно 2 вопроса:

1. Можно ли заставить работать проект с jsp, не переписывая бек-енд, если да, то как подружить spring core с jsp, может, нужно в мавене депенденси определенные добавить, в общем, подскажите, как это сделать, или ссылочку подкиньте на пример.
2. Если нет, то только вариант переписать все с использованием Spring MVC? Ибо все туториалы, что нашел, идут с этой связкой.

Answer (score 1):

Странный у вас вопрос. Если разобрались с JSF и Spring, можно и с сервлетами разобраться. Но вообще всегда с них начинают. Не пойму, как вас могли взять на работу без знаний сервлетов и JSP.

Comment: Ну так получилось) Так тут нет сложности разобраться, я, собственно, это и сделал, у меня просто культурный шок, видя кашу из java и html, это примерно как научится ездить на автомате, а потом пересесть на механику.  
Так бек-энд, я так понял, можно не переписывать, просто web.xml донастроить, правильно?!